# JQuery push array to specific element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm making a webapp with the help of JQuery to keep track of goals & habits.
One can add a main goal such as 'Discipline', and then afterwards can attach subgoals or habits to said main goal (e.g. 'work out everyday').

Organizing the array for main goals is obvious;

goals = ['Acceptance', 'Discipline', 'Accountability'];

I however have found no way in JQuery/Javascript to attach/add an array of items to a specific item in ANOTHER array.

Is there an easier way to do this, with JSON for example ?

Thanks in advance for any help offered

Answer (score 2):

You do this by storing an array of *objects* at the top level, with a property for the child array

```
var goals  = [{
  name: "Acceptance",
  children:[]
},{
  name: "Discipline",
  children:[]
},{
  name: "Accountability",
  children:[]
}];
```

When it comes to adding your child you just push it to the child array

```
goals[0].children.push("Work out every day");
```

Another option is store key/values at the top level

```
var goals = {"Acceptance":[],"Discipline":[],"Accountability":[]};
```

Slightly less versatile, but adding an item to a specific element slightly easier

```
goals["Acceptance"].push("Work out every day");
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Would you have an idea as to why the children.push method isn't having any result ? No error, just nothing getting pushed.

Comment: @lvb Not from that description no. Make a [mcve] and post a new question. Feel free to link to the new question here and I'll take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038058/jquery-pushing-array-to-array-item-child-not-working