# Jquery pushing array to array item child not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an app to track goals & the habits that those goals consist of.

I am however having trouble pushing the habits array to a specific goal.

I can declare the array of main goals & show the 'name' elements in html after getting the saved goals.

```
var _priValues  = [{
        name: "test1",
        children:[]
    }];

let storedValues = localStorage.getItem("_priValues", JSON.stringify(_priValues));
```

However, once I try to push a value to the children of the goal, as such:

```
_priValues[0].children.push("Work out every day");
```

Or like this:

```
_priValues.push({
            [id] : {
                name : "maingoal",
                children : "subgoal"
            }
        });
```

The HTML will not show anymore and the array remains the same - no children are added to the main goal.

How I show the HTML (which is working fine as long as I dont push children):

```
for (var i = 0; i < _priValues.length; i++) { 
  var item = `
    <h6>${_priValues[i].name}</h6>     
    <ul class="collectionDetails">                                        
      <li> ${_priValues[i].children} </li>                                  
    </ul>`; 
  $('.priorityList ul.collection').append(item); 
};
```

Anyone have any idea as to why it's not working ?

I'm using Materialize for CSS & Cordova/phonegap to test it out, if that helps.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see where you're sending the changes to HTML.

Comment: Edited to show how I show it in HTML

Comment: you're not iterating over the children array in your html

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the array itself, but `children` is *also* an array

```
for (var i = 0; i < _priValues.length; i++) { 
  var item = `
    <h6>${_priValues[i].name}</h6>     
    <ul class="collectionDetails">                                        
      ${_priValues[i].children.map(child => "<li>" + child + "</li>"}                           
    </ul>`; 
  $('.priorityList ul.collection').append(item); 
};
```

The above uses [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to turn the `children` array to a list of `li`.

---

Also that doing this:

```
_priValues.push({
        [id] : {
            name : "maingoal",
            children : "subgoal"
        }
    });
```

redefines `children` as a simple string (Welcome to Javascript, where you can change types at runtime!). What you probably meant to do there is:

```
_priValues.push({
        [id] : {
            name : "maingoal",
            children : ["subgoal"]
        }
    });
```

Note the addition of `[` & `]` keeping `children` as an array with 1 element.

---

Here is an example of your code working as (I think) you expect:

```js
var _priValues = [{
  name:"Foo",
  children:["bar"]
}];


function redraw(){
  $('.priorityList').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < _priValues.length; i++) { 
    var item = `
      <h6>${_priValues[i].name}</h6>     
      <ul class="collectionDetails">                                        
        ${_priValues[i].children.map(child => "<li>" + child + "</li>")} 
      </ul>`; 
    $('.priorityList').append(item); 
  };
}
redraw();

$('.addItem').on("click",() => {
   _priValues.push({
      name:"new-item", children:["item1"]
   });
   redraw();
})

$('.addChild').on("click",() => {
   _priValues[0].children.push("new-item");
   redraw();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="priorityList">
  
</div>

<button class="addItem">Add new top level item</button>
<button class="addChild">Add a new child to the first item</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! This will no doubt be useful, but the main issue right now is still that I cannot push to the children array, so even if I could show it on HTML - it would show nothing as there are no child values

Comment: @lvb as ive said before - [mcve] which is not what you have above.

Comment: @lvb I've added a [mcve] of my own, perhaps you could use that as a starting point to show what _your code_ is doing differently